# Glider.js con api de películas (MovieDB), no muestra las películas con el efecto carrusel

Tags: javascript, api, fetch, slider, carrusel

## MovieDB con glider.js no me funciona bien del todo

Hola hice una pagina de peliculas con la **api de MovieDB**, pero al intentar implementar hacer un carrusel con glider.js, **no me carga bien el carrousel**, me muestra las portadas pero aparecen encimadas, por lo que no esta aplicando el efecto de carrusel de glider.js.
Yo creo que es, por que al cargar las imagenes con javascript mediante un api, este se demora en cargar por lo que glider.js no puede leer las peliculas, ya que todavia no han sido creadas.
Solamente me funciona cuando en el **addEventListener lo pongo en scroll**, de lo contrario si lo utilizo con load no funciona, pero yo quiero que se carguen correctamente **al iniciar la pagina no al scrollear**.

```
      if (respuesta.status === 200) {
        const datos = await respuesta.json();
        let cors = [];
        datos.results.forEach((pelicula) => {
          //movie es el poster de la pelicula
          const movie = pelicula.poster_path;

          if (cors.length <= 1000) {
            //en cors estoy guardando los posters
            cors += `<div class='carousel_images'><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie}"></div>`;
            //inserto cors al html
            document.getElementById("carousel__lista").innerHTML = cors;

            //Estructura del Carrousel con glider.js
            window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
                new Glider(document.getElementById("carousel__lista"), {
                  slidesToShow: 4,
                  slidesToScroll: 2,
                  dots: ".carousel__indicadores",
                });
              }
            );
          }
        });
```

> Cabe resaltar que ya utilize glider.js con imagenes fijas de mi ordenador y me funciona bien, por lo que quiero pensar que el problema es al agregarlo con imagenes de una API.

Por favor si alguien me ayuda se lo agradeceria, a la mejor la respuesta es algo obvio y solo es poner un await o algo simple, pero ya estuve modificando un monton y **no puedo hallar la solucion**

*Si necesitan mas informacion haganmelo saber con gusto se las dare*

Comment: Con el evento `"scroll"` te da el resultado que esperabas, pero con el evento `"load"` no? Eso entendí, puede ser? De ser así, probá usando el evento `"pageshow"` y cuenta que resultado te dió

Comment: @Liyo, no me funciona tampoco, es que no se que pasa pero con el evento scroll aparecen desordenadas, pero al scrollear se ordenan como espero, sin embargo con las demás como **"load"** para que cargue la pagina directamente sin tener que hacer algo, no funciona.

Comment: El problema que tienes es que al suscribirte al evento `load` o `pageshow` el consumo de la API aun no termina. Por eso el `scroll` si te funciona (estas scrolleando unos instantes mas tarde). Deberías suscribirte al cambio de la clase `carousel_images` , para eso te recomiendo [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Así, cuando hayan terminado los cambios de dicha clase `MutationObserver` lo evaluará y podrás correr `new Glider`.